# Is 219 is a quadratic residue mod 383 (Legendre symbols)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

The notes of my course have the example below, but I think there is a mistake.

[image]

Isn't the 3rd = from the bottom up supposed to be
$\left(\frac{2}{383}\right)\left(\frac{3}{383}\right)^2$
And then,
$=\left(\frac{2}{383}\right)=1$?

If the example is actually correct, could you explain why?

Many thanks!

Comment: No.  The fourth line from the bottom ought to have read $\left( \frac {18}{73}\right)$.

Comment: @lulu thanks! I got this now